# Question how to make some application seen from 'application list'?

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-for-android

i install 'android studio' on my Ubuntu. 
The location of the 'android studio' folder is on folder 'opt' - and to run the application i need to open the terminal on the 'opt/android studio/bin' and run ./studio.sh

1. Is it possible to make some shortcut on the desktop and run the 'android studio' on one click
2. Why i can't see the executable file from the 'all application' of the Ubuntu ?

Comment: this is not duplicate !!! those are two different question

Comment: I recommend you read the answer for the duplicate question